# How to hover over and pause the time in AngularJs Interval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a time in my UI where in the time is continuously updated using the AngularJS Interval. Even the Milliseconds are contunously running. Keeping that in mind is it possible to pause the time When i hover over it. Help is really appreciated. Below are the codes.

**Image of the UI**

[image]

**html**

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row ">
 <div class="col-lg-12 text-center" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<h3  ><b id="thetime">{{theTime| date:'hh:mm:ss sss a'}}</b></h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**AngularJS Code**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.theTime = new Date();

  $interval(function () {
      $scope.theTime = new Date();    
  }, 6);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `ng-mouseover` stop interval function in `ng-mouseleave` start interval function

```
    $scope.startInterval = function(){
         $scope.flag = $interval(function(){
                        $scope.theTime = new Date();
                    }, 6);
    }

    $scope.stopInterval= function(){
       if($scope.flag)
       $interval.cancel($scope.flag);
    }
    $scope.startInterval();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/7qo4jtjv/

Comment: Thanks fr Responding ..but that doesnt work ..the time itself stops moving. It remains stopped.

Comment: Wow!! now that was awesome. Thanks a lot buddy.